# Register a package for the class generated from the proto file in the gradle by default , not in proto file

Tags: android, gradle, protocol-buffers

In my android app I use proto files. For example, I have proto file Stats.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
package com.me.test;

message Stat {
    string a = 1;
    string b = 2;
    string c = 3;
    string d = 4;
}
```

I need to register package in the each proto file itself, and this is uncomfortable, because I have a lot of files. I want to register default package in gradle, for example, 'package com.me.test', which uses each file that I create. I found [solution](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/issues/6#issuecomment-98193641) in javanano

```
nano {
    proto {
      // Selects between --java_out and --javanano_out, default is 'java'
      mode 'javanano'
      // Options added to --java_out or --javanano_out
      option 'java_package=src/proto/simple-data.proto|my_package'
      option 'java_outer_classname=src/proto/simple-data.proto|OuterName'
      // Apply the 'grpc' plugin defined in protobufNativeCodeGenPluginDeps
      plugin 'grpc' {
        // Options added to --grpc_out
        option 'nano=true'
      }
    }
```

But I need to use javalite

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                remove java
            }
            task.plugins {
                javalite { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to have analogous logic

```
option 'java_package=src/proto/simple-data.proto|my_package'
```

like javanano in javalite

Can I implement that?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the doc](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#configure-what-to-generate), and assuming `javalite` supports the same features than `java` (it's a long shot as I did not found any trace of documentation on this plugin), just try that :

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                remove java
            }
            task.plugins {
                javalite {
                    option 'java_package=.......'                 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

edit : try that in order to inspect the object :

```
task.plugins {
    javalite {
        it.properties.each { println "$it.key -> $it.value" }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case for every proto-file during gradle synchronization get error
Cause: protoc: stdout: . stderr:
com/me/test/StatOuterClass.java: Tried to write the same file twice.
Car.java: Tried to write the same file twice.
etc.
I think that cause is calling javalite both in task.builtins and task.plugins, but if we remove javalite in task.plugins, we also get error
Cause: protoc: stdout: . stderr: protoc-gen-javalite: program not found or is not executable
--javalite_out: protoc-gen-javalite: Plugin failed with status code 1.

Comment: what about moving `option 'java_package=.......'` in the `javalite` block of `plugins` ? (and removing `javalite` in `builtins`). I edited my answer

Comment: in this case generate class don't fit into path that we indicate in option 'java_package=.......', our path don't influence for path of this generate class. btw, in this case we haven't any errors during gradle sync

Comment: @ToYonos Maybe you know the way to fix the problem mentioned by Alherd in his last comment? I will award the bounty if I see that your solution is fully usable

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. As  I underlined, I did not find any documentation about how  to configure `javalite` in the `protobuf` context.

Comment: I edited my answer, maybe you can inspect the `javalite` object in order to get clues